# Transferring a TLS/SSL certificate via serial

Tags: linux, character-encoding, serial-port, at-command

I need to send a PEM-formatted certificate for storaging on a module that can be communicated with through the AT command set via a serial interface on one of Linux device nodes in `/dev`.

So far I've been using mostly

```
echo 'AT' > /dev/ttyX
```

to issue the necessary commands and it has done the trick just fine.

Any output from the device is monitored with `cat /dev/ttyX` on another terminal window.

I now have a certificate file encoded with ANSI. The documentation tells me to input it to the module using only `LF` line breaks and to terminate the input with `Ctrl+Z`, which I believe is hex `0x1A`. The document also specifies that the certificate file may not end with an `EOF` character. I have used a hex editor to verify that the file is formatted as it should be.

I've tried to use both `echo` and `printf` to send the certificate chars / string to the module.

I have tried to include the 0x1A character in both the file and send it separately after the certificate chars like so:

`printf '\x1a' > /dev/ttyX`

or alternatively

`echo -n -e '\x1a' > /dev/ttyX`

The module seems to acknowledge the `0x1A` as it stops the `>`-prompt for certificate and gives me the most verbose reply ever: `ERROR`

Generally, I'm sending the certificate file contents as follows:

`echo -e "$(cat certfile)" > /dev/ttyX`

or

`printf '%b' "$(cat certfile)" > /dev/ttyX`

Please assume that I have access to basic Linux shell tools (such as `echo, printf, nano, stty` and so on) with no option to trivially install new ones. I use SSH to access the target device and `pscp` to transfer the file to the target device. I also have a Windows rig on the side.

Any suggestions what else I should take into consideration? Maybe an `stty` option that I've missed? Does `cat` do something nasty in the input phase? A revealing trick to investigate the actual character data about to be send to the module? Some weird kink with serial comms I've missed?

If I

`printf '%b' "$(cat cert)" > ./testoutput`

and

`od -x testoutput`

the file looks alright in hex (I reordered the output from `od -x` manually, it seems to make pairs of the hex digits and switch them around). For example the end is:

`2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 45 4e 44 20 43 45 52 54 49 46 49 43 41 54 45 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a 1a 00`

There must be something in `stty` or the receiving end that's causing trouble. Right?

Answer (score 0):

> For example the end is:
>
> `2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 45 4e 44 20 43 45 52 54 49 46 49 43 41 54 45 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a 00 1a`

Wait a sec. What's that `00` doing there, right before the `1a`?

That doesn't belong. Try removing it.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's an anomaly alright. Something along the way is adding it. Looking with a hex editor on Windows side it looks like`2D 2D 0A 1A`. 

`od -x` shows it even in the original file I've transferred to the Linux device. Anomaly with file transfer or the output from `od`? o; I'm not sure how I should go about removing it on the Linux side.

Comment: Actually, the end is `1a 00`. A programming error in my brain caused me not to switch around the last hex pair output by `od`.